# ODP.NET Configuration in Web.config

Tags: .net, oracle, odp.net

I'm adding the odp configuration in the application web.config file. For this I have a configuration section named "oracle.dataaccess.client". Therefore I'm adding an entry in the `<configSections>` section. 
Something like this:

```
<section name="oracle.dataaccess.client" type="System.Data.Common.DbProviderConfigurationHandler, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
```

I'm not sure about the type parameter.
My question is, what value must i use for the type parameter? Where can I find it?
The Oracle client is 9.2. The .net framework is 1.1

Comment: you are missing the "something like this" part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ODP 9.2 was released before .Net 2, and does not implement the new interfaces and factories this framework added (in the System.Data.Common namespace)

In other words, you cannot configure this version of ODP via the System.Data.Common configuration entries. ADO.net 2.0 compatibility started with version 10.2.0.2 of ODP (see http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/06-winsupp/win06odp.html for instance)

Comment: Dead link above

Answer (score 1):

check also the [Oracle® Data Provider for .NET Developer's Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/win.111/e10927/featConfig.htm)

Edit:

OK, so I guess this is what you are looking for:

Add under `<configuration> <configsections>` the following entries to web.config:

```
<section name="oracle.dataaccess.client" 
type="System.Data.Common.DbProviderConfigurationHandler, System.Data, 
Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
```

Add under `<system.data> <DbProviderFactories>` the following entry

```
<add name="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" 
invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider 
for .NET" type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, 
Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.102.2.20, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
```

Comment: I've already checked that link. The information is not in the guide